# Верстка сайта

Tags: html, контент, css

Как сделать, чтобы область дива контент немного перекрывала див футер?

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow-x: hidden;   
}
a {
    color: blue;
    outline: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 18px
}
img {
    border: none;
}
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;

}

/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#header {
  margin: 0 0 0 -148px;
  width: 1280px;
    height: 522px;  
    background-image: url(images/head.jpg);
    background-position: center top;

}

/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#content {
    margin: -120px auto 0;
    width: 950px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #09192a;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#footer {
  width: 1280px;
    margin-top: -215px;
    height: 310px;
    background-image: url(images/footer.png);
    z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

/* Logo
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#logo {
  padding: 26px 0 0 0;
  margin: 0px auto 0;
  width: 516px;
  height: 225px;
}

#logo img{
  width: 515px;
  height: 199px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.. Не подскажите как сделать чтобы футер был по центру, тоесть на 1280на1024 все норм, при выборе 1024на768 смещается сильно в право!?

Comment: попробуйте:<br><br>
clear:both;<br>display:block;<br>margin:auto;<br>

Comment: Может код дадите?

Comment: вот код!

Comment: @kros, не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: Более правильно. Первая цифра верх-низ, вторая право-лево.

      margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 2):

у футера:

```
z-index: ставим меньше, чем у контента;
position: relative;
margin-top: -XXpx;
```

обычно достаточно, но при сложной вложенности рекомендуется тестировать, особенно в фаерфоксе.

Answer (score 1):

Вопросы у вас ставят в тупик однако)))
Попробовать поиграться с `z-index; position: absolute; margin-top: -xxpx;` где `xx` число.
На вскидку тяжело ответить на подобный вопрос, потому как нужно смотреть поведение браузеров. И тестить, тестить, тестить.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="content" style="z-index:2; height:55px;">Контент</div>
<div id="footer" style="z-index:1; height:50px;">Футер</div>
```

Comment: это при учёте статичного размера тела контента, а если сайт должен быть "резиновый" по высоте?

Comment: ну тогда за место пикселов использовать проценты